# sbt 0.11.1 doesn't retrieve scalatra 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

I've just upgraded to sbt `0.11.1` that doesn't seem to be fetching a
certain dependency. Things worked fine before the upgrade.

I have this dependency:

```
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % "2.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
```

And when I `compile`:

```
> update
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Nov 18, 2011 5:44:16 PM
> compile
[info] Compiling 29 Scala sources and 1 Java source to
/home/yang/pod/sales/scala/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[error] /home/yang/pod/sales/scala/src/main/scala/com/pod/Web.scala:125:
not found: type ScalatraServlet
[error] class PodWeb extends ScalatraServlet with ScalateSupport with
FileUploadSupport {
[error]                      ^
[error] class file needed by ScalateSupport is missing.
[error] reference type ScalatraKernel of package org.scalatra refers
to nonexisting symbol.
[error] two errors found
[error] {file:/home/yang/pod/sales/scala/}pod/compile:compile:
Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 10 s, completed Nov 18, 2011 5:44:45 PM
```

The file seems to be missing:

```
$ ls /home/yang/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatra/scalatra_2.9.1/jars/
scalatra_2.9.1-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
```

The file exists in the repo, though:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/scalatra/scalatra_2.9.1/2.1.0-SNAPSHOT/

This is still happening even if I blow away `~/.ivy2/`. Any hints what's happening?

Complete `build.sbt` below:

```
name := "pod"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

seq(coffeeSettings: _*)

seq(webSettings :_*)

seq(sbtprotobuf.ProtobufPlugin.protobufSettings: _*)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalaquery" % "scalaquery_2.9.0" % "0.9.4",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.0-801.jdbc4", // % "runtime",
  "com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.7.1.RELEASE",
  "ru.circumflex" % "circumflex-orm" % "2.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "ru.circumflex" % "circumflex-core" % "2.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "net.sf.ehcache" % "ehcache-core" % "2.4.3",
  // snapshots needed for scala 2.9.0 support
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % "2.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % "2.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-fileupload" % "2.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.fusesource.scalate" % "scalate-jruby" % "1.5.0",
  "org.fusesource.scalamd" % "scalamd" % "1.5", // % runtime,
  "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.22",
  "net.debasishg" % "sjson_2.9.0" % "0.12",
  "com.lambdaworks" % "scrypt" % "1.2.0",
  "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.22" % "container",
  // "org.bowlerframework" %% "core" % "0.4.1",
  "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.1",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math" % "2.2",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.0",
  "com.google.protobuf" % "protobuf-java" % "2.4.1",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.29",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.9.0" % "1.6.1",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.158",
  "pentaho.weka" % "pdm-3.7-ce" % "SNAPSHOT",
  // this line doesn't work due to sbt bug:
  // https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/issues/263
  // work around by manually downloading this into the lib/ directory
  // "org.rosuda" % "jri" % "0.9-1" from "https://dev.partyondata.com/deps/jri-0.9-1.jar",
  "net.java.dev.jna" % "jna" % "3.3.0",
  "org.scalala" % "scalala_2.9.0" % "1.0.0.RC2-SNAPSHOT",
  "rhino" % "js" % "1.7R2",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.9",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.2",
  "commons-validator" % "commons-validator" % "1.3.1",
  "oro" % "oro" % "2.0.8", // validator depends on this
  "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided->default"
)

fork in run := true

javaOptions in run ++= Seq(
  "-Xmx3G",
  "-Djava.library.path=" + System.getenv("HOME") +
  "/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13/rJava/jri:" +
  "/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/jri"
)

//javaOptions in run ++= Seq(
//  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote",
//  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3000",
//  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false",
//  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
//)

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-g:vars", "-deprecation", "-unchecked")

// needed for the scalatra snapshots
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "POD" at "https://dev.partyondata.com/deps/",
  "Scala-Tools Snapshots" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/",
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  "Sonatype OSS releases" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases",
  "ScalaNLP" at "http://repo.scalanlp.org/repo",
  "Pentaho" at "http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/pentaho/",
  "FuseSource snapshots" at "http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots",
  "JBoss" at "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases"
)

initialCommands in consoleQuick := """
import scalala.scalar._;
import scalala.tensor.::;
import scalala.tensor.mutable._;
import scalala.tensor.dense._;
import scalala.tensor.sparse._;
import scalala.library.Library._;
import scalala.library.LinearAlgebra._;
import scalala.library.Statistics._;
import scalala.library.Plotting._;
import scalala.operators.Implicits._;
//
import scala.collection.{mutable => mut}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import ru.circumflex.orm._
import ru.circumflex.core._
"""

//
// sxr
//

// addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-tools.sxr" %% "sxr" % "0.2.7")
// 
// scalacOptions <+= (scalaSource in Compile) { "-P:sxr:base-directory:" + _.getAbsolutePath }
```

Comment: Please show the configuration file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After blowing away not just ~/.ivy2 but ~/.m2 and ~/.sbt as well, everything worked again.

Comment: awesome, thanks! deleting something in ~/.ivy2 fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes ivy cache entries get corrupted - simply remove `~/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatra/scalatra_2.9.1/jars/`, and let SBT re-fetch the dependency from the remote repo. If it doesn't work, try to remove an entire cache directory (`~/.ivy2/cache`).

Comment: This is still happening even if I blow away `~/.ivy2/`....  I'll add this to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I have had occasions where Ivy has got confused. I can't tell you why, unfortunately, but I have found that things work fine after deleting the entire ~/.ivy2 directory hierarchy. Clearly you'll have to download all your dependencies again, though :-(

Comment: This is still happening even if I blow away ~/.ivy2/. I'll add this to my original question.