# Cannot import scalate, after downloading with SBT

Tags: sbt, scalate

my `build.sbt` has

```
libraryDependencies += "org.fusesource.scalate" % "scalate-core" % "1.6.1" from "http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/fusesource/scalate/"

resolvers += "FuseSource Public Repository" at "http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/public"
```

i ran

```
$ sbt update
```

which successfully downloaded everything cf

```
[info] downloading http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/fusesource/scalate/ ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.scalate#scalate-core;1.6.1!scalate-core.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/fusesource/scalate/ (617ms)
```

but when i try to use it

```
$ sbt console
> import org.fusesource
```

the transitive dependencies `hawtjni` and `jansi` are in scope, but not `scalate`

what am i doing wrong?

UPDATE:

i checked for `~/.ivy2/cache/org.fusesource.scalate/`, it exists.

ANSWER:

solved by [sbt 0.11.1 doesn't retrieve scalatra 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193321/sbt-not-fetching-dependency)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "FuseSource Public Repository" at
  "http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/public"

libraryDependencies +=
  "org.fusesource.scalate" %% "scalate-core" % "1.6.1"
```

I did two things:

1) Use `%%` not `%` so the Scala version is automatically appended to the artifact name. (It would also work to use `%` but change `scalate-core` to `scalate-core_2.10`, assuming you're on some Scala 2.10.x version.)

2) Omit the `from` clause. You don't need it if you have the resolver right.

After adding these settings to an empty sbt 0.13 project I see:

```
> show fullClasspath
[info] Updating {file:/Users/tisue/foo/}foo...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/scalate/scalate-core_2.10/1.6.1/scalate-core_2.10-1.6.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.scalate#scalate-core_2.10;1.6.1!scalate-core_2.10.jar(bundle) (1265ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/scalate/scalate-util_2.10/1.6.1/scalate-util_2.10-1.6.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.scalate#scalate-util_2.10;1.6.1!scalate-util_2.10.jar(bundle) (274ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1!slf4j-api.jar (198ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] List(Attributed(/Users/tisue/foo/target/scala-2.10/classes),
            Attributed(/Users/tisue/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.2/lib/scala-library.jar),
            Attributed(/Users/tisue/.ivy2/cache/org.fusesource.scalate/scalate-core_2.10/bundles/scalate-core_2.10-1.6.1.jar),
            Attributed(/Users/tisue/.ivy2/cache/org.fusesource.scalate/scalate-util_2.10/bundles/scalate-util_2.10-1.6.1.jar),
            Attributed(/Users/tisue/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar),
            Attributed(/Users/tisue/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.10.0.jar),
            Attributed(/Users/tisue/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.10.0.jar))
```

Indentation added for clarity. Note that the main scalate jar was downloaded to `~/.ivy2/cache/org.fusesource.scalate/scalate-core_2.10/bundles/scalate-core_2.10-1.6.1.jar`.

Comment: thanks, but still won't import. where should i find the library? `find . | grep scalate` shows nothing.

Comment: I added a transcript showing where the jars end up, and also how you would find out where they ended up. Sam's advice to nuke `~/.ivy2` is good; botched attempts to use `from` may have left bad files there.

Comment: thanks! i remember seeing stuff like "org.fusesource.scalate#scalate-core_2.10;1.6.1!..." but not like "List(Attributed(...))", i'll pay more attention next time. also, "botched" meaning i used `from` when i should not have, or i C-c'd some process, or both `from` and not `from`, or what?

Comment: If you use `from` to tell sbt "dependency A is at this URL, I promise you!", then sbt will believe you, and not just believe you, but cache the retrieved artifact too. I don't think that changing the URL in a `from`, or removing the `from` entirely, triggers retrieval from the correct location of something that sbt already has in cache that is bad because it came from an incorrect location.

Comment: I would _think_ and _hope_ Ivy is robust about C-c, network going blooey, etc., but I don't know it for sure.

Answer (score 1):

nuke `~/.ivy2` and/or `~/.sbt` and/or `~/.m2`

... i should've checked one dir at a time, or subdirs, but i'm itching to write my bitcoin price monitor ;)